# React Js ad Node Js stripe payment is becoming incomplete at stripe dashboard

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

I was adding stripe payment in my project . I was using react-stripe-checkout and at backend was using node js with stripe installed.
At frontend I have inside render() :

```
const payNow= async token=>{
    try{
        const response = await axios({
            url : `/mycardpay/${localStorage.getItem('slno')}`,
            method : 'post',
            data : {
                amount : this.calculateTotalAmount(),
                token,
            }
        });

        if(response.data.message == 'Success'){
            console.log(response.data)
        }

    }catch(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

than added :

```html
<StripeCheckout   
    stripeKey="pk_stripekey..."  
    label='Pay Now'  
    name='Pay With Credit Card'  
    billingAddress   
    amount={this.calculateTotalAmount()*100}   
    description={`Your Total Amount $${this.calculateTotalAmount()}`}  
    token={payNow} 
/>
```

AT my backend I have :

```
const Stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.Secret_Key); 

async function paymentCard(req, res, next){
    try{
        const {usersl} = req.params;
        const {token, amount} = req.body;
        
        try{
            console.log(amount)
            console.log(token)
            console.log(token.card.last4)
            const customer = await Stripe.customers.create({
                email: token.email, // Use the email from the token
                source: token.id, // Use the token ID as the payment method source
              });
              
            await Stripe.paymentIntents.create({
                amount: amount, // Amount in cents
                currency: 'inr',
                payment_method_types: ['card'],
                payment_method: token.card.id, // Use the card ID from the token's card object
                customer: customer.id, 
                confirm: true,
                    
            })
```

It is the portion of my code that handles stripe payment and take the api to stripe server .
I am getting perfectly fine token.

```
{
  id: 'tok_1Ng5esSI10A4W78jlyIUAMLX',
  object: 'token',
  card: {
    id: 'card_1Ng5erSI10A4W78j5WRiJWUm',
    object: 'card',
    address_city: 'dhaka',
    address_country: 'Bangladesh',
    address_line1: 'asdad',
    address_line1_check: 'unchecked',
    address_line2: null,
    address_state: null,
    address_zip: '1244',
    address_zip_check: 'unchecked',
    brand: 'Visa',
    country: 'US',
    cvc_check: 'unchecked',
    dynamic_last4: null,
    exp_month: 4,
    exp_year: 2026,
    funding: 'credit',
    last4: '4242',
    name: 'asdad asd',
    tokenization_method: null,
    wallet: null
  },
  client_ip: '103.110.161.4',
  created: 1692276638,
  email: 'arnobsamin95@gmail.com',
  livemode: false,
  type: 'card',
  used: false
}
```

Why in stripe website at payment i see it not succeded, I see it incomplete

I am expecting it to be completed.

Comment: You most likely have to capture the payment after it's been created

Comment: Sir i'm working with it for first time can you tell how pleaseeeee!!!!!!

Comment: First, not a sir. Not everyone on the internet is male. I've never used Stripe, so I can't tell you how. But I do know with Paypal and other payment processors I've worked with, you have to create the order/payment (which seems to be what you've done so far), authorize the payment, then capture the payment. From their [API documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents), it looks like they have Confirm and Capture as endpoints. https://stripe.com/docs/payments/paymentintents/lifecycle#intent-statuses might also be of some help

Comment: Firstly, I'm really sorry. Also, I saw all other places they just insta get completed payment after what i did .... At my case paypal worked fine. But, stripe causing issues twice :<
I tried to charges.create() also .....
That say api can't be used in my region.
Than I tried it and it successfully taking api and does everything ins tripe website till it get 
"3D Secure attempt incomplete
The cardholder began 3D Secure authentication but has not completed it.
Aug 17, 2023, 6:50 PM"
I created /rout/payment in nodejs backend it is getting token from frontend fine ....

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this packages [github source](https://github.com/azmenak/react-stripe-checkout), it appears to be several years out of date and is an implementation of [Legacy Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/legacy-checkout) which Stripe deprecated several years ago.

Depending on what exactly you're trying to achieve, you should either integrate using Stripe's modern [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout) product, or look at leveraging `@stripe/react-stripe-js` to build a custom payment form ([minimal example](https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-js#minimal-example)).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just solved it finally.
Latest stripe is way to secured and old methods in other tuts not work cause it sends require_action in backend after paymentIntents.
So, we add another mode at frontend react js name @stripe/stripe-js.And add just few lines.
At backend inside /payment (I used /mycardpay) rout :

```
 const customer = await Stripe.customers.create({
                email: token.email, // Use the email from the token
                source: token.id, // Use the token ID as the payment method source
              });

            
            const paymentIntent = await Stripe.paymentIntents.create({
                amount: amount, // Amount in cents
                currency: 'inr',
                payment_method_types: ['card'],
                payment_method: token.card.id, // Use the card ID from the token's card object
                customer: customer.id, 
                confirm: true,
                   
            })



            if (paymentIntent.status === 'requires_action') {
                // Return client_secret and requires_action to the frontend
                console.log('1')
                return res.status(200).json({
                    requires_action: true,
                    client_secret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
                    payment_method: paymentIntent.payment_method,
                });
            } else if (paymentIntent.status === 'succeeded') {
                console.log('2')
                return res.status(200).json({
                    message: 'Success',
                });
            } else {
                // Handle other paymentIntent statuses
                console.log('3')
                return res.status(500).json({
                    message: 'Payment failed',
                });
            }
```

Than at Frontend we similiarly use react-js-checkout at start to start the payment.But, inside token={payNow} we add the process to handle require_action.

```
import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js';
const payNow= async token=>{
                const stripePromise = loadStripe('pk_test_........');
                try{
                    const response = await axios({
                        url : `/mycardpay/${localStorage.getItem('slno')}`,
                        method : 'post',
                        data : {
                            amount : this.calculateTotalAmount(),
                            token,
                        }
                    });
        
                if (response.data.requires_action) {
                    console.log('1')
                    const { client_secret,  payment_method} = response.data;
                    const stripe = await stripePromise;
                    
                    // Handle the customer action using Stripe.js
                    const result = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(client_secret, {
                        payment_method: payment_method.id,
                    });
    
                    if (result.error) {
                        console.log('1')
                        // Handle any error during customer action
                        console.error(result.error);
                    } else {
                        console.log('2')
                        // Payment completed successfully
                        console.log('Payment successful:', result.paymentIntent);
                    }
                } else if (response.data.message === 'Success') {
                    console.log('3')
                    // Handle success without customer action
                    console.log('Payment successful:', response.data);
                }
    
            }catch(err){
                console.log(err)
            }
        }
```

And start the whole process with your method to call .

```
<StripeCheckout   
stripeKey="pk_Test......"  
label='Pay Now'  
name='Pay With Credit Card'  
billingAddress   
amount={this.calculateTotalAmount()*100}   
description={`Your Total Amount $${this.calculateTotalAmount()}`}  
token={payNow} 
/>
```

`this.calculatetotalAmount()` is just my function that calculate all product data cost it's nothing much.